# KeyError: 'bpy_prop_collection[key]: error

Tags: python, rendering, animation, texturing, objects

I tried to fix my error with the error message "KeyError: 'bpy_prop_collection[key]: key "Sun" not found' ". The "Sun" is the object that I set up in the blender and the error pointed to this  `Sunobj = bpy.data.objects['Sun']` So is there any way to that I fix this error?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure your Sun is named "Sun" and not something like "Sun.001" ? Are you sure there is a sun in your scene? You can also access objects by their index instead of their name. For example, if your sun is the fourth object in the scene, you may be able to access it with Sunobj = bpy.data.objects[3]